# OpenCSV infinte loop when line has missing quote

Tags: java, opencsv

I am reading in very large (millions of rows) CSV files that come from a remote source which I have no control over. I am using OpenCSV which is working great, until today. Today's file has a single bad line in it that looks something like

```
col1,col2,col3,"col4, ""stuff"" and yeah, \", col5, col6, col7...\r\n
```

The extra \ on the end is breaking OpenCsv so that readNext never returns. I suspect it is seeing that as an escaped quote, and there by the quoted field is not closed. If i remove the \ all is good. Put it back, it breaks again.

Since readNext never returns I do not have a good way to capture the error an intercept it.

My *guess* is that it is trying to load the entire rest of the file (100s of thousands of rows) in to col4 and choking.

What I would prefer is an error that I can catch, report, and move on to the next line in the file. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - I figured out a way. Originally I was using:

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(this.fullFileName), ',','"', 1);
```

Then had a loop like so:

```
while ((csvLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
..do stuff..
}
```

That call to readNext() never returns when it hits that bad record. So there is no way to catch it. Changing the code to use CVSParser instead:

```
fileLines = Files.readAllLines(new File(this.fullFileName).toPath(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(delimChar,quoteChar);
    for (String nextLine : fileLines) {
        try {
            csvLine = csvParser.parseLine(nextLine);
            ...do stuff...
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ...report bad record and stuff..  
        }
    }
```

Now, when that record is hit, CSVParser will throw an exception, which I can catch and do stuff with.

The primary drawback to this is that multi-line records will not work, but in my use case that is not a problem. I do not know a solution for multi-line records.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using **Java's opencsv** library, so you can use the following **API** `CSVReaderBuilder.withMultilineLimit()` to solve this problem:

```java
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(reader)
         .withSkipLines(hasHeader ? 1 : 0)
         .withRowProcessor(rowProcessor)
         // Sets the maximum number of lines allowed in a multiline record.
         .withMultilineLimit(1000) 
         .withCSVParser(new RFC4180ParserBuilder().build())
         .build();
```